# only vaildation in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Can I use Serializer just for validation purpose?
for example if I had CommentSerializer as

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

Is it as as per motive of DRF to use this serializer **just for validation of request or some data without refering to any Django models**? For example:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
class MyAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = CommentSerializer(data=dict(request.data))
        if serializer.is_valid():
            validated_data = serializer.validated_data
        # do something with validated_data
        # return some data as Response()
```

or am I fighting against the framework guidance?

Comment: I'm not really following why you want to do that? Normally a request should *do* something: retrieve data, or create/update/delete data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem edited my question for clarity purpose. My question "is it perfectly vaild for serializer to just only validate the data without touching Django models? does it follow the norm/purpose of django-rest-framework?"

Comment: well you can do whatever you want with a serializer. So I don't see why not. But often you can use a `ListAPIView`, etc. which implements a fixed scenario. This is usually safer.

Comment: Absolutely you can. You can define your own custom serialisers and do what you like, model or no model.